# How to delete a blank sheet if MSSQL query is blank?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
#create excel doc
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SeriesofSheets.xlsx')

#sql query
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
script = """
select *
from TblCustomersA with (nolock)
"""
#run query
cursor.execute(script)

#write query to sheet
df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Customers A')

#sql 2nd query
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
script = """
select *
from TblCustomersB with (nolock)
"""
#run query
cursor.execute(script)

#write query to sheet
df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Customers B')

#Save the excel document
writer.save()
```

All of this code + my actually SQL connection works fine for creating the Excel document and subsequent sheets.

What I'd like to do is throw an If/then statement that will look at Row 2 for data. If it's missing, to delete the sheet.

I tried something like this:

```
active_sheet = df.get_sheet_by_name("Customers B")

if active_sheet['A2'].isnull():
    df.remove_sheet(active_sheet)
else:
    Continue
```

However, I got a data type error. How do I check if my query got no results and then skip that sheet?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: MSSQL. When the query runs, it completes and gives me headers, but the rest of the query will sometimes have no results. I intend to run multiple queries and create several sheets, but just don't want to save my excel document with sheets that only have headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the length of your dataframe. If it is > 0 then write to the file. Also, you do not need o use `cusrsor.execute(q)` if you are going to use [`pd.read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html). Pandas will take care of executing your query.

You can also improve your code by iterating through a list of table name and executing your query in the loop. Your table name in your query will simply use an [`f-string`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to pass the correct table name value - note that f-string require python 3.6+.

I tested it on my end using an Oracle database and it returned the expected results. Let me know if you have issues with MSSql though.

```
#create excel doc
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SeriesofSheets.xlsx')

tables = ['TblCustomersA', 'TblCustomersA']
customers = ['Customer A', 'Customer B']


#iterate through your tables and write them to the excel doc
for i in range(len(tables)):
    #sql query
    q = f"""
    select *
    from {tables[i]} with (nolock)
    """

    #write query to sheet
    df = pd.read_sql_query(q, cnxn)

    if len(df) > 0:
        #assign the specific sheet's name by using our customer list
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{customers[i]}')
        writer.save()
```

Comment: This works perfectly! It's interesting to me that the len works here at 0. Does the header not count towards the length?

Comment: Awesome. Do not hesitate to mark it as solve so that anyone with a similar issue can find this answer. 
`len(df)` will be called against the index of the dataframe, so columns will not be included.